# using django-easy_thumbnails from view

Tags: python, django, django-apps

easy_thumbnails is a big help when making models or views for thumbnails.

I am using the templatetag (via template, not via model) and easy_thumbnails creates sucessfully the thumbnail files.

what happen when I want to use easy_thumbnails via view, not model o templatetag (the rendering of the images is via ajax, and django will not parse the templatetag...) for example imagine displaying infinite image thumbnails for this plugin http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/dynamic_ajax_php.html . any lights? thanks!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're asking about, but README file from `easy_thumbnails` should cover your use case. 
And if for some reason it doesn't and you want to use {% thumbnail %} tag directly in a view, then you can always `render_to_string` a template that contains just: {% thumbnail %} tag, although this looks to me like a hack.